# Resource not found OpenAIEmbeddings

Tags: openai-api

why am i getting this error when runnning streamlit app via vscode that connects to the azure databricks?

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings( openai_api_key="hardcoded", deployment="text-embedding-ada-002", openai_api_base="https:.....", openai_api_type="azure", chunk_size=1 )

NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}} Traceback: File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script exec(code, module.dict) File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\streamlit\streamlit_app2.py", line 129, in main() File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\streamlit\streamlit_app2.py", line 106, in main qa = load_db(files, "stuff", 4) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\streamlit\streamlit_app2.py", line 67, in load_db db = DocArrayInMemorySearch.from_documents(docs, embeddings) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\vectorstores.py", line 510, in from_documents return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\docarray\in_memory.py", line 69, in from_texts store.add_texts(texts=texts, metadatas=metadatas) File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\langchain\vectorstores\docarray\base.py", line 82, in add_texts embeddings = self.embedding.embed_documents(list(texts)) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 556, in embed_documents return self._get_len_safe_embeddings(texts, engine=engine) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 432, in _get_len_safe_embeddings response = embed_with_retry( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\langchain\embeddings\openai.py", line 107, in embed_with_retry return embeddings.client.create(**kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\openai\resources\embeddings.py", line 105, in create return self._post( ^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\openai_base_client.py", line 1096, in post return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls)) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\openai_base_client.py", line 856, in request return self._request( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "D:\Users\yusuf.demir\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\uitest4\Lib\site-packages\openai_base_client.py", line 908, in _request raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None

i was expecting the codes running smoothly